# PhpStorm internal terminal font distortion

Tags: encoding, terminal, phpstorm

After moving some config files from my home to my work PC (just my custom color scheme and keymap), the integrated terminal of PhpStorm 2016 looks like this with UTF-8 encoding:

[image]

where it should be like:

[image]

I've set the terminal to use Git bash instead of CMD (I'm on win8.1), but also changing back to CMD doesnt make any difference.

I've tried to change the IDE encoding to default (windows-1253) or anything else but doesnt seem to have any effect on the terminal.

Comment: This is more like font corruption to me.... Try different font for Console (in PhpStorm settings)

Comment: This was indeed a font problem.. 'Monaco' font was set as default for terminal and it is even displayed distorted in preview. Changing it to eg. 'Consolas' fixed this, when I opened a new terminal tab. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like font corruption to me...

Please try different font for Console (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Console Font`) or try re-installing currently used font.